# Create a trigger when Inserting Data Row and check specific Column that have values in given range

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, triggers

Trigger not working. I just want to do not allow enter marks that not in range to database.

This is the code I've tried.

The table

```
CREATE Table Marks
(
    TestID VARCHAR(10),
    StudentID VARCHAR(10),
    Grade CHAR(1),
    Marks FLOAT,
    IssuedDate VARCHAR(10),

    PRIMARY KEY (TestID, StudentID),
    CONSTRAINT FK66 
        FOREIGN KEY(TestID) REFERENCES Test(TestID),
    CONSTRAINT FK77 
        FOREIGN KEY(StudentID) REFERENCES Student(StudentID)
)
```

The trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER checkRange
ON Marks
FOR INSERT
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @marks FLOAT
    DECLARE @tID VARCHAR(10)
    DECLARE @stID VARCHAR(10)

    SELECT @marks = Marks, @tID = TestID, @stID = StudentID
    FROM inserted

    IF (((@marks) < 0) AND ((@marks) > 100))
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION

    DELETE FROM Marks 
    WHERE TestID = @tID AND StudentID = @stID
END
```

Inserting the data:

```
INSERT INTO Marks 
VALUES ('T02','ST00000001','F',110,'2019-08-24')
```

Comment: You're making trigger 101 mistake, `Inserted` can have 0-N rows, not just 1. You have to treat it like you would any table and use set-based operations, not procedural logic. The [Reference Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/triggers/use-the-inserted-and-deleted-tables?view=sql-server-ver15) show how. And what does "Trigger Not Working" actually mean?

Comment: I just found problem in here 'IF(((@marks)<0) AND ((@marks)>100))'  Trigger is working when i changed 'IF(@marks > 100.00)' I want to check if marks blow 0 and above 100.

Comment: I founded answer 'IF((@marks > 100.00) OR (@marks < 0.00))' Thanks for Helping

Comment: That doesn't work if you insert 2 rows though.

Comment: Why use a trigger here at all? A `CONSTRAINT` seems like a much better solution.

Comment: `IssuedDate VARCHAR(10),` NO NO NO NO NO. Think about your datatypes! This is just flat wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned by others, your trigger has a number of serious issues.

It appears you need the `Marks` column to be within 0-100 per test per student, if so a much better solution is a check constraint:

```sql
ALTER TABLE Marks
    ADD CONSTRAINT CHK_Marks
        CHECK (Marks >= 0 AND Marks <= 100);
```

Answer (score 0):

The better answer by far is a `check constraint`. But I will leave mine here so you understand triggers better.

What you are actually looking for is something like the following, which handles the fact that `Inserted` can have 0-N rows (your current solution will break when `Inserted` contains anything other than 1 row).

And given you have already issued a `ROLLBACK` there is probably no reason to `DELETE` anything, unless you want to delete rows added previous to the current `INSERT` statement.

```
CREATE TRIGGER checkRange
ON Marks
FOR INSERT
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    IF EXISTS (
        SELECT 1
        FROM Inserted I
        WHERE Marks > 100.00 OR Marks < 0.00
    ) BEGIN
        --ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
        -- Don't rollback in a trigger, throw instead. "A rollback causes a weird error The transaction ended in the trigger. The batch has been aborted" (thanks Charlieface).
        THROW 51000, 'Marks are out of range, either > 100 or < 0.', 1; 
    END;
END;
```

Notes, in my opinion:

- `varchar(10)` is a terrible choice for a PK, why not use an `int identity`?
- `float` is a terrible choice for Marks, unless you are storing scientific information you should never use `float` because it doesn't store a precise number. You want a `decimal(9,2)` or similar for this.
- `varchar(10)` is a terrible choice for a date, use a `date` datetype else you'll be having issues with this for the rest of its life.

Comment: `varchar(10)` is not a terrible choice for `studentid` assuming it never changes (it may represent a username for instance), it's only 10 bytes and if other tables are queried based on ID then it saves a join

Comment: Note also that grouping by the primary key means you don't actually group, so the `group by` is a waste of time

Comment: ^^ true dat, I didn't look at the table design in detail. I wouldn't use username as a PK, that creates all sorts of other complexity to ensure that remains unique and to allocate in the first place.

Answer (score -2):

```
IF((@marks > 100.00) OR (@marks < 0.00))
```